# Need to add/remove class from TD of the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Need To Add/Remove Class from TD of table, based on button click. By Default all the TD will be hidden. While clicking button, i need to enable the respective TD alone.

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eVj8V/2/

Code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .hideThis {display: none;}
        td, th {
                    border: thin solid;
            }
    </style>

    <script>

        function constrctTable() {
            var TableRef = document.getElementById("TableConstruction");
            TableRef.innerHTML = "";
            var table = "";
            table += "<table>";
            table += "<tr style='border: inherit;' id='tableColumns'>";
            table += "<td>S.No</td>";
            table += "<td>Name</td>";
            table += "<td class=hideThis>Employee No</td>";
            table += "<td class=hideThis>Manager No</td>";
            table += "<td class=hideThis>Clerk No</td>";


            table += "</tr>";
            for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
                table += "<tr class=recordRow>";
                table += "<td>"+i+"</td>";
                table += "<td>Raj "+i+"</td>";
                table += "<td class=hideThis name='Employee'>"+ i +"</td>";
                table += "<td class=hideThis name='Manager'>"+ i +"</td>";
                table += "<td class=hideThis name='Clerk'>"+ i +"</td>";
                    table += "</tr>";
            }
            table += "</table>";

            TableRef.innerHTML = table;
        }


        function enableEmployee(enableRef) {
            $('.hideThis:contains(' + enableRef + ')').removeClass('hideThis');
            $('.recordRow td.hideThis[name=' +enableRef+ ']').removeClass('hideThis');
            $('.recordRow td.hideThis[name !=' +enableRef+ ']').addClass('hideThis');
        }


        function enableManager(enableRef) {
            $('.hideThis:contains(' + enableRef + ')').removeClass('hideThis');
            $('.recordRow td.hideThis[name=' +enableRef+ ']').removeClass('hideThis');
            $('.recordRow td.hideThis[name !=' +enableRef+ ']').addClass('hideThis');
        }

        function enableClerk(enableRef) {
            $('.hideThis:contains(' + enableRef + ')').removeClass('hideThis');
            $('.recordRow td.hideThis[name=' +enableRef+ ']').removeClass('hideThis');
            $('.recordRow td.hideThis[name !=' +enableRef+ ']').addClass('hideThis');
        }   

    </script>

</head>

<body onload="constrctTable();">

<div id="TableConstruction"> </div>

<button type="button"   onclick="enableEmployee('Employee')"> Employee </button>
<button type="button"   onclick="enableManager('Manager')"> Manager </button>
<button type="button"   onclick="enableClerk('Clerk')"> Clerk </button>
</body>


</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello please check this answer , I am not sure you are looking for this answer http://jsfiddle.net/EB5jq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use attribute selector because `Employee` is the value of `name` attribute.

```
$('.recordRow td.hideThis[name="Employee"]').removeClass('hideThis');
```

Also you can fine tune the selector to include only tds with the class `hideThis`

- The `hideThis` class is assigned to `td` so you need to remove it from `td` - no need to use  :has()
- :contains checks for text content, in your case you are checking the value of an attribute - use attribute selector

Comment: Thanks for your post. It solve my problem, but it not disable other TD. I updated my code. Why it is not disable other TD which contain other name value ?

Comment: please help me to resolve this issue... Why [name !="Employee"] is not working in the updated above code. I need to hide other TD.

Comment: I updated the same in Jsfiddle in my post. Please refer it and let me know where im doing wrong. updated the Post.

Comment: @Hariharan a much more cleaner way http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gwVt2/2/ - there are html changes

Comment: Thanks Arun, I miss explain my requirement cleanly. Will update it shotly in Jsfiddle. Sorry for my mistake

Comment: Updated the JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/eVj8V/2/) ... Sorry for my miss explanation.

Comment: Hope now you can understand my query. I need to enable and disable based on checkbox selection.

Comment: Anyway thanks for your help. But still searching for solution.

Comment: It seems that, we should not add extra words in class="hidethis". with help of name i need to achieve it. please refer my try code as http://jsfiddle.net/eVj8V/2/

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you. im trying this for 3 days... still unable to achieve success. Main-thing is to not change or add extra in class

Comment: in the else block i used $('*[class=""]').addClass('hideThis');   still it remove all the TD

Answer (score 0):

In your context name is an attribute not the text, so that you have to use attribute selector to achieve what you want.

Try,

```
$('.recordRow').find('td.hideThis[name="Employee"]').removeClass('hideThis');
```

As per your new request you can do like this,

```
var allTds = $('.recordRow').find('td');
var employeeTd =  cache.find('.hideThis[name="Employee"]');
allTds.not(employeeTd).addClass('hideThis');
employeeTd.removeClass('hideThis');
```

Comment: The class `hideThis` is assigned to `td` so you need to remove it from `td`, in your case you are trying to remove it from the `tr` - you are trying to remove the class `hideThis` from a tr with class `recordRow` and has td with class `hideThis` and `name` attribute value `Employee`

Comment: Thanks for your post. It solve my problem, but it not disable other TD. I updated my code. Why it is not disable other TD which contain other name value ?

Comment: please help me to resolve this issue... Why [name !="Employee"] is not working in the updated above code. I need to hide other TD

Comment: @Hariharan You have already removed that class, so that your code should be like this  `$('.recordRow td[name !=' +enableRef+ ']').addClass('hideThis');`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its not working, I updated the same in Jsfiddle in my post. Please refer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using the JavaScript, do it with CSS:

```
table td + td + td + td {
   border: none;
 }
```

I am providing this solution because it might be possible that user haven't provided the permission for JavaScript on his browser, in that case your code will not work.

You can find similar questions here:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/